# htaccess error leading to loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I am trying to force SSL on HTACCESS file and all my efforts result in a loop on index.php.

This is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My site works fine with this but no SSL.

I tried the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.fakedomainlollol.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The updated rewrite rule sends the site in a loop.

What is the error? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your first rule is redirecting https to https ,thats why the loop.

Comment: put  this line above the rule **RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$** so that only http requests can route to https, not https => https.